# MySQL very long queries

Tags: mysql, wordpress, join, timeout, mysql-workbench

I have an quite large db (800+Mb dump file) that I imported to my local server. Its a Wordpress db from witch i need to extract certain posts. There is around 160000 posts inside.

Currently im testing a bit with MySql Workbench running simple queries with JOIN and it requires a lot of time, so long actually that Workbench stops processing.

Here`s an example:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*)
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships 
  ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy 
  ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
LEFT JOIN wp_terms 
  ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id
WHERE wp_terms.term_id = 195;
```

Running over 600 seconds.
Here is an wordpress db schema:
[image]

Of course chance is I'm just bad at SQL, not really my field...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have all indexes on columns you use for joining (wp_posts.ID, wp_term_relationships.object_id etc.), this should not be a problem, and query should be executed in less than 1 sec (1 sec is a lot, too).

Also, there might be waiting on other queries in queue (locks), so you should add this to those queries:

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED ;

SELECT 
COUNT(*)
FROM
wp_posts
    LEFT JOIN
wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
    LEFT JOIN
wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
    LEFT JOIN
wp_terms ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id
    WHERE
wp_terms.term_id = 195;

COMMIT ;
```

Create indexes in workbench. I can see here that you are joining on IDs on every table, so because those are ID columns, they should be PRIMARY KEY, and create UNIQUE Clustered index on them.

Comment: There are no other queries that I know of. I dont think that table is indexed. I got it as dump and imported it running large txt file (bunch of queries). If I  index it in MySQL workbench and then connect to it with Eclipse (JAVA), will table still be indexed?

Comment: The problem was that during db import, last couple of queries didnt execute, most of them were indexing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really just running a count you can get your result with:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM wp_term_relationships wtr
   JOIN wp_term_taxonomy wtt
     ON wtt.term_taxonomy_id = wtr.term_taxonomy_id
  WHERE wtt.term_id = 195;
```

You don't need the information from the obligatory `wp_terms` or `wp_posts` records that are attached to these records.
You also don't need a `LEFT JOIN` as you are discarding `NULL` tuples with your `WHERE` condition.

As for the speed, I would suggest running the query prepended with `EXPLAIN` and checking that everything is indexed correctly and these indices are being used.

Comment: This is just a test querry. I really need to pull data from table, so joins are required.